# Why does my floating point value have an `E` character when I convert it to a string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, floating-point-conversion, string-conversion

```
txtDebugLog.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
    fps.Frame();
    ggg = fps.GetFPS();
    txtDebugLog.Text = String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}", ggg, txtDebugLog.Text);
})
```

`txtDebugLog` is a TextBox.

Using a breakpoint i see on `ggg` in this example it's value is:

```
0.00000102593151
```

Then i click on continue and see in the `TextBox`:

```
1.025932E-06
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to understand why your value is formatted as a string in exponential format.

Comment: Just a comment: I think your question was reasonable in itself; I think the downvotes are due to the apparently low effort you've put in into describing the problem you were seeing.

Comment: Not merely in describing the problem you were seeing, also in figuring out what's going on. This behaviour is explained in the right places that you should have been able to find by reading the documentation yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your floating point value `ggg` has a very small value. When you convert it to a string, as happens in this call

```
String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}", ggg, txtDebugLog.Text);
```

it will be converted to a string that uses an **exponential** format to represent that value. You can read about what an exponential format is, also referred to as scientific notation, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

If you want to use a different format, you have to specify that yourself. Many standard formats are available, that you can explicitly specify when doing a conversion. The conversion of a `double` to a `string` using a specific format can be done by calling the **[`double.ToString(format)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** method.

Several standard formats are available and listed there, including the output you will get from them.

The default format that is used if you do not specify one, is the [General Format Specifier ("G")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GFormatString), which:

> Converts a number to the **most compact** of either fixed-point or
>   scientific notation, depending on the type of the number and whether a
>   precision specifier is present. The precision specifier defines the
>   maximum number of significant digits that can appear in the result
>   string.

Answer (score 2):

From [the sub-section "E notation" of the Wikipedia article on "scientific notation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation):

> Most calculators and many computer programs present very large and very small results in scientific notation, typically invoked by a key labelled EXP (for exponent), EEX (for enter exponent), EE, EX, or E depending on vendor and model. Because superscripted exponents like 10<sup>7</sup> cannot always be conveniently displayed, the letter E or e is often used to represent times ten raised to the power of (which would be written as "× 10<sup>b</sup>") and is followed by the value of the exponent; in other words, for any two real numbers a and b, the usage of "aEb" would indicate a value of a × 10<sup>b</sup>. Note that in this usage the character e is not related to the mathematical constant e or the exponential function e<sup>x</sup> (a confusion that is less likely with capital E); and though it stands for exponent, the notation is usually referred to as (scientific) E notation or (scientific) e notation, rather than (scientific) exponential notation (though the latter also occurs).